# Failed Test Not Running When Selected in pyCharm

Tags: pycharm, pytest

It used to be that I could run the tests in a pyunit test file by using RMB to run all the tests.  Then I could run individual tests by using the RMB on a failed test and running that test individually.

Something seems to have changed in the latest update.  pytest is being launched with a -k option which is trying to use the test name as a keyword expression.  This isn't working and so the test is always deselected.

Any idea where the switch is to turn this off and how it got turned on?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug [PY-31181](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-31181).

The workaround is that you don't RMB on a single test and select "Run.." or "Debug..."  Instead select `Create 'pytest for test...`.  This will bring up a dialog box that creates the configuration to run this test.

Blank out the "Keywords" field and all will be well.

Protip: Also select "Single instance only" in the upper right hand corner while you have the dialog box open.